# Facebook Authorize App Script

Tags: php, facebook, api

Does ANYONE have a working (php) facebook authorize app (in iframe) script. I've tried all the scripts I can find on google none of them work. I just want it to authorize the app and go the the proper page after authorization. With or without a button to start the authorization process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = "[YOUR APP ID]";

     $canvas_page = "[YOUR APP URL]";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

Comment: this is my canvas url on facebook: http://www.gamerholic.com/q&a/

should my canvas url in the script be the page that holds the app? separate from the index.php page?

Comment: the app page is the canvas page, so yes.